# How to display blob image in img tag in Vue.js application?

Tags: image, vuejs2, blob

I saved the image to database in the following format:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU...
```

When I get that image from database, I see in "Network" tab in "Response" section the following:

```
"planimetry": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
      100,
      97,
      116,
      97,
      58,
      ...
```

In Vue.js template I have:

```
<img
  :src="sectionData.planimetry"
/>
```

The sectionData I'm getting as a prop, and planimetry is type of BLOB.

The issue is the image is not displayed that is: src="[object Object].

How to display the image?

Comment: Does `planimetry.data.map(b => String.fromCharCode(b)).join('')` get you back to the original format?

Comment: Yes. Please, write your comment as regular answer and I'll mark it as correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers 100, 97, 116, 97, 58 are just `data:` in ASCII. This suggests that the array is just the bytes of your original image format.

You could get back to the original format using something like this:

```js
planimetry.data.map(b => String.fromCharCode(b)).join('')
```

This should be sufficient to use it as the `src` of an `<img>`.

I would expect this to be fixed on the server rather than in the UI if possible. If it were returning the raw bytes of the image then fair enough but `data:image/png;base64` should really just be transferred as a string.